# Django ModelForms - Display different choice than what will be saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

From the title this sounds like something I shouldn't wanna do. But I have two models. Both have AutoField PK's and model B has a foreign key ID for A.

In my form to create B, I have all of B's fields including the foreign key ID. This simply shows up to the user as something like "B Object 1". This is absolutely useless to me as when I have more items I'd rather have a name to identify it to the user.

So my question is: can I substitute A.name in place of the foreign key ID, but still save just the foreign key when it comes to saving the model?

Comment: The foreign key just displays the  `__str__` method of `B`. So you can override this method and add your own way of represeting the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `__str__` in your model B. That should change the 'friendly' output for the model, and you can compose a string with multiple values as well.

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.your_field
```

Comment: `__unicode__` is replaced by `__str__`  from django 2

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!